# How to call extra async method in Tornado?

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, python-3.5

I want to call an async method from other libraries in tornado, like so:

```
class Database:
    async def find_info(user_id):
        pass

class TestClass(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        db = Database()
        user = yield db.find_info(user_id=id)
        return self.write(user.username)
```

But it goes to something like sleeping mode and I'll never get any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which other libraries? Most async functions are written for a particular event loop (Tornado, asyncio, Twisted, etc). Different event loops don't cooperate unless you ask them to. You probably want to enable Tornado/asyncio interoperability with [`tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/asyncio.html#tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By `AsyncIOMainLoop` can I create my own library which can corporate with Tornado?

Comment: The choice of IOLoop implementation is up to the application, not libraries. If you want to write a library you can choose to use either tornado.ioloop.IOLoop or asyncio.EventLoop (the generic interfaces of each framework)